# Help figuring out output signal of LTI system.

Tags: fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems, fourier-series, control-theory

Would greatly appreciate any help in figuring out the output signal of my discrete time LTI system.

My input signal is cos(ωn) and my frequency response is H(e^jω)=(1+e^−jω)/2.

Comment: Ask the moderators to _migrate_ this question to dsp.SE where it is a much better fit. _Please_ do not just post this question on dsp.SE; ask to **migrate** this one.

Answer (score 4):

The steady state response to an input $n \mapsto e^{i \alpha n}$ is
$n \mapsto \hat{H}(e^{i \alpha}) e^{i \alpha n}$.

Note that $\cos  ( n \omega) = {1 \over 2} (e^{in \omega} + e^{-in \omega})$.

Hence the response to the $\cos$ input will be
$n \mapsto {1 \over 2} (\hat{H}(e^{i \omega}) e^{i n \omega} + \hat{H}(e^{-i \omega}) e^{-i n \omega})$.

We see that $\hat{H}( e^{-i \omega}) = \overline{\hat{H}( e^{i \omega})}$, so the
response is $n \mapsto \operatorname{re} (\hat{H}( e^{i \omega}) e^{i n \omega})$.

Note that $\hat{H}( e^{-i \omega}) = {1 \over 2} (1+e^{-i \omega}) = e^{-i { \omega \over 2}} \cos \omega$, so the response is
$n \mapsto \operatorname{re} (e^{-i { \omega \over 2}} (\cos \omega )  e^{i n \omega}) = \cos \omega \operatorname{re} (  e^{i (n-{1\over 2}) \omega}) = \cos \omega \cos((n-{1\over 2}) \omega)$.

**Note**: A simpler solution would be to note that the given $\hat{H}$ corresponds to the system $y_n = {1 \over 2} (u_n + u_{n-1})$. Then a direct computation yields the above answer.

Comment: Thank you that makes things so much clearer!
Hmm so does that leave us with y[n]=1/2cos(πn)

Comment: No. It would give you $y_n = {1 \over 2}(\cos (n \omega)+\cos((n-1)\omega))$, and using a trigonometric identity, you will end up with the same result as above.